# How can I 'prepare' objects in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to 'prepare' complete groups of layers and styles into some sort of object so I can quickly recall it in another document?

With 'prepare' I mean store them the same way you can store layer-styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose your desired layers, click Layer>Smart Objects>Convert to smart objects.
Then you get one Smart Object which you can double click in the Layers Panel and edit is separately, with all you previous layers intact.